# specialize function for tuple parameter in C++11

Tags: templates, c++11

I want to specialize a function for **any** tuple parameter.
It should be something like this:

```
template <class T>
void f(T t) { ...code for default.. }

template <>
void f<std::tuple<...>> (std::tuple<...> t) } { ... code for tuples... };
```

It seems to be something related to **template template parameters** but I didn't find any example for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't partially specialize a function; amongst available solutions, the best would be to introduce an overload instead:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) {}

template <typename... Ts>
void f(std::tuple<Ts...> t) {}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbe2d8879660a7e3)

Comment: Now that I see the it looks very obvious. I think I don't have good intuitions about overloading and templates yet.